# Reallocating memory in C

Tags: c, realloc

I Think I am having a problem with reallocing the token character pointer, please help.
i googged how to realloc but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it because I am getting MEMORY CORRUPTION error when I run my program.

```
char* token = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
token[0] = '\0';
int c;
do{         
    c = fgetc(fp);
    if(isalnum(c)){ //add to char array
        if(isalpha(c))
            c = tolower(c);
        if(token[0] == '\0'){
            token[0] = (char)c;
            token[1] = '\0';
        }
        else{
            token = (char*)realloc(token, strlen(token)+2);
            int len = strlen(token);
            token[len] = (char)c;
            token[len+1] = '\0';
        }
    }
    else{ //token
        if(token[0] != '\0'){ //add token
            struct token* newtoken = (struct token*)malloc(sizeof(struct token));
            newtoken->token = (char*)malloc(strlen(token)*sizeof(char));
            strcpy(newtoken->token, token);
            newtoken->records = NULL;
            struct record* newrecord = (struct record*)malloc(sizeof(struct record));
            newrecord->fileName = (char*)malloc(strlen(fileName)*sizeof(char));
            strcpy(newrecord->fileName, fileName);
            newrecord->freq = 1;
            tokens = (struct token*)addToken(tokens, newtoken, newrecord);
        }
        token[0] = '\0';
    }
    if(feof(fp))
        break;
}while(1);
```

Comment: Your first malloc only allocates room for 1 char. I think you want at least 2 chars.

Comment: One obvious problem: you need to allocate `strlen(s) + 1` prior to `strcpy`, since `strlen` does not include the nul-terminator character. You also don't need those messy casts before `malloc`.

Comment: `char* token = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` are you sure this is correct? sizeof(char) is always **1**, so you are going to cause some trouble by accessing `token[1]`...

Comment: @Naytzyrhc: `sizeof char` is defined to be 1, but `token[1]` would be invalid regardless of the size.

Comment: I would suggest you allocate a block of memory first, when that is used up allocate a new block. It is not effective to allocate/realloc a few bytes a time.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
char* token = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

More clearly expressed as `char *token = malloc(1);`, this allocates 1 byte.

But then you go:

```
token[0] = (char)c;
token[1] = '\0';
```

which writes 2 bytes into a 1-byte allocation. This is a buffer overflow and may be the cause of your memory corruption. You could fix this by malloc`ing two bytes to start off with.

You also overwrite your buffers later:

```
newtoken->token = (char*)malloc(strlen(token)*sizeof(char));
strcpy(newtoken->token, token);
```

Change to:

```
newtoken->token = malloc( strlen(token) + 1 );
strcpy(newtoken->token, token);
```

Notice how my version has fewer warts than yours too, so it is easier to read and therefore easier to spot if there are any errors.

The next `strcpy` after that also has the same problem.